# remove adjacent duplicates in r

Tags: r, duplicates, apply

I have a data frame in the format :

```
site_domain <- c('ebay.com','facebook.com','facebook.com','ebay.com','ebay.com','auto.com','ebay.com','facebook.com','auto.com','ebay.com','facebook.com','facebook.com','ebay.com','facebook.com','auto.com','auto.com')
id <- c(1, 1, 1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
file0 <- as.data.frame(cbind(site_domain,id))
```

I did a group by on "id" to get the data :

```
library(dplyr)
xx <- as.data.frame(file0 %>% 
                      group_by(id) %>%
                      summarise(pages=paste(site_domain, collapse='_')))
```

The data looks like:

```
1 ebay.com_facebook.com_facebook.com
2 ebay.com_ebay.com
3 auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com
4 ebay.com_facebook.com_facebook.com
5 ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com_auto.com
```

However i want to remove adjacent duplicates, so i want out put like :

```
1 ebay.com_facebook.com
2 ebay.com
3 auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com
4 ebay.com_facebook.com
5 ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com
```

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `values` property of `rle` to remove adjacent duplicates.

```
library(dplyr)
file0 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(pages=paste(rle(as.character(site_domain))$values, collapse='_'))

#      id                                   pages
#    <fctr>                                   <chr>
#1      1                   ebay.com_facebook.com
#2      2                                ebay.com
#3      3 auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com
#4      4                   ebay.com_facebook.com
#5      5          ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(file0)[,  unique(site_domain), by= .(id, grp=rleid(site_domain))
             ][, .(site=paste(V1, collapse="_")) , id]
#   id                                    site
#1:  1                   ebay.com_facebook.com
#2:  2                                ebay.com
#3:  3 auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com
#4:  4                   ebay.com_facebook.com
#5:  5          ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com
```

---

Or create an index with `.I`, extract the rows, and `paste` by 'id'

```
i1 <- setDT(file0)[, .I[!duplicated(site_domain)], .(id, grp = rleid(site_domain))]$V1
file0[i1, .(site = paste(site_domain, collapse="_")), by = id]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `unique` function:

```
xx <- as.data.frame(file0 %>% 
                      group_by(id) %>%
                      summarise(pages=paste(unique(site_domain), collapse='_')))

xx

#  id                          pages
#1  1          ebay.com_facebook.com
#2  2                       ebay.com
#3  3 auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com
#4  4          ebay.com_facebook.com
#5  5 ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com
```

Comment: this looks fine , however i see in the 3rd row : output should be `auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com` but this approach gives : `auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com`.. any help how can we amend this.

Comment: Yes its possible I will update the answer with new approach

Answer (score 1):

it is easy to remove the duplication before grouping

```
      file0 <- file0  [!duplicated(file0),]


        site_domain id
       1      ebay.com  1
       2  facebook.com  1
       4      ebay.com  2
       6      auto.com  3
       7      ebay.com  3
       8  facebook.com  3
       10     ebay.com  4
       11 facebook.com  4
       13     ebay.com  5
       14 facebook.com  5
       15     auto.com  5
```

then you can group the data by id

```
           id                          pages
            1  1          ebay.com_facebook.com
            2  2                       ebay.com
            3  3 auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com
            4  4          ebay.com_facebook.com
            5  5 ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com
```

Comment: this too comes close, however  output should be : `auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com_auto.com` but this approach too gives : `auto.com_ebay.com_facebook.com`.. any help how can we amend this